# When using vector in c++, what happens when something else replace vector?

Tags: c++, class, vector

First of all, I'm sorry for my lack of English skill.
In this assignment, int main function is given and I'd like to create a class. but I don't get how `vector` is replaced with `Tv_show_info` in function here, `Tv_show_info<int>viewers("file1.txt");`
So I guess Tv_show_info is actually an user-defined name and viewers is a vector created inside the class?
Asking questions about coding is always so tough :(
I don't know how to google search this. Please help.

```
/*class Tv_show_info //<-is this correct?
{
    
};*/

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Tv_show_info<int>viewers("file1.txt");
    Tv_show_info<std::string>show_names(argv[2]);
    
    int n=viewers.info.at(0);
    std::string s=show_names.info.at(0);
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're aiming for `std::vector<Tv_show_info> viewers;` a `vector` that contains a collection of `Tv_show_info`s. Then `viewers.at(0).some_Tv_show_info_member_variable` to access a member variable. Note that you have to put `Tv_show_info`s into the list before you can access it.

Comment: `Tv_show_info` must be defined somewhere. It is probably a class template (but could also be an alias template). And it has a member named `info`. Perhaps that `info` is a `std::vector`. But without seeing the actual `Tv_show_info` definition, I'm just guessing.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I kind of get the idea even though I don't fully understand it. At least I can start working on this.